# VBA code for excel - delete rows that contain only capital letters, data is not like

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to determine the code to remove rows that contain all uppercase letters. The data I am preparing is contained in one worksheets from rows `1:900`.  The way the current data reads is ;

```
I WANT TO DELETE THIS LINE
I want to keep this line 
243-4291 GASKET I want to keep this line
```

In this case, all that I have managed to do so far is remove rows with uppercase, however if you look at the 3rd line the work GASKET is upper case,  I need to keep that line.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Gary's suggestion, run backwards as to not skip iterations.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Sub DelCaps()
For i = 900 to 1 Step -1
If Range("A" & i).Value = UCase(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

That's set for column A, if it's not obviously change it. Tested, I think it solves your problem if I understand you correctly.

EDIT: This will also delete rows with BLANK cells in the A column. If you don't wish to do so, the if statement changes to:

```
If Range("A" & i).Value = Ucase(Range("a" & i).Value) and Range("a" & i).Value <> "" Then
```

Comment: Hi Joe:  Consider running the loop backwards.